# Repeat Array Shuffle

Tags: ios

Goal: get the array to reshuffle itself when NSUInteger *current iterates over the final index. Any help would be awesome.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
   [self buttonMechanics];
}

- (void) generateArray {
    NSUInteger count = [box count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    NSUInteger nElements = count - i;
    NSUInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
    [box exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
}



- (void) buttonMechanics {
    if(current + 1 < [box count])
    {
        current++;
        post = [box objectAtIndex: current];
        [showItemLabel setText: post];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want more descriptive method names. `buttonPressed` is not a good name; name it something having to do with the action that is triggered by the button press, like `shuffleArray`. The others are also non descriptive, especially `buttonMechanics`.

Second, to appropriately shuffle an array, use something like the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It's very easy to implement.

Third, if you want to shuffle an array multiple times (not really worth it with a properly implemented Fisher-Yates), just do a for loop over your shuffle function.

Here's a simple Objective-C shuffle function:

```
NSArray * shuffleCards(NSArray *cards) {
    NSMutableArray *mutableCards = [cards mutableCopy];
    for (NSInteger i = mutableCards.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)i);
        [mutableCards exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    }

    return [mutableCards copy];
}
```

If you want to call the function multiple times, just loop over it like this:

```
NSArray *cards = @[@1, @2, @3, @4];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cards = shuffleCards(cards);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. The (void)generateArray is, what I thought, already the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm. It functions really well for the randomization process but I don't understand how to get the array to re-shuffle itself, once it's been iterated through.

Comment: You would just call your shuffle method (after you break your shuffle into its own method) multiple times, possibly in a small for loop, depending on the number of times you want to shuffle.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just really struggling with where to put the loop or the multiple calls. I've tried various approaches but no matter what I do, once the iterator hits the last array index, it just stays put.

Comment: I've edited the answer with an example. Resetting the index isn't necessary; just call the shuffle function multiple times. But like I said I don't think you'll get much value out of it.

Comment: I figured it out. Super appreciate the feedback and for being patient!